# How to make a Cheat Code for Tkinter GUIs

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

The Clicker GUI I've been making has been coming along nicely, however, whenever I change the code it takes me at least half an hour to get to the point where I can test it (even more if luck is against me) and if I have made a single error then I have to fix it and restart the waiting process again just to find another error which I wasn't able to test before. I've tried adding a cheat code in before to just skip me to a certain stage but it didn't work and I have no idea why.

```
    def New_Option1(self):
        self.labelVariable3 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label3 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable3, anchor='e', fg='black')
        label3.grid(column=0, row=2,columnspan=2,  stick='EW')
        self.labelVariable3.set(u"         Mana:")

        self.labelVariable4 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label4 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable4, anchor='w', fg='black')
        label4.grid(column=2, row=2, stick='EW')
        self.labelVariable4.set(Mana)

        self.labelVariable5 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label5 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable5, anchor='w', fg='black')
        label5.grid(column=0, row=0,  stick='EW')
        self.labelVariable5.set('Level:')

        self.labelVariable6 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label6 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable6, anchor='w', fg='black')
        label6.grid(column=1, row=0, stick='EW')
        self.labelVariable6.set(Level)

        button2 = tkinter.Button(self, text=u"Concentrate", command=self.OnButtonClick2)
        button2.grid(column=2, row=4)

def New_Option2(self):
        self.labelVariable6.set(Level)

        self.labelVariable7 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label7 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable7, anchor='e', fg='black')
        label7.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=2, stick='EW')
        self.labelVariable7.set('   Monsters:')

        self.labelVariable8 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label8 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable8, anchor='w', fg='black')
        label8.grid(column=2, row=3, stick='EW')
        self.labelVariable8.set(Monsters)

        button3 = tkinter.Button(self, text=u"     Summon     ", command=self.OnButtonClick3)
        button3.grid(column=0, row=5, columnspan=2)

        button4 = tkinter.Button(self, text=u"    Fireball    ", command=self.OnButtonClick4)
        button4.grid(column=2, row=5)

    def New_Option3(self):
        self.labelVariable6.set(Level)

        self.labelVariable9 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label9 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable9, anchor='w', fg='black')
        label9.grid(column=3, row=0, stick='EW')
        self.labelVariable9.set('Gold:')

        self.labelVariable10 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label10 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable10, anchor='w', fg='black')
        label10.grid(column=4, row=0, stick='EW')
        self.labelVariable10.set(Gold)

        self.labelVariable11 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label11 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable11, anchor='e', fg='black')
        label11.grid(column=3, row=1, columnspan=2, stick='EW')
        self.labelVariable11.set('Teachers:')

        self.labelVariable12 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label12 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable12, anchor='w', fg='black')
        label12.grid(column=5, row=1, stick='EW')
        self.labelVariable12.set(Teachers)

        button5 = tkinter.Button(self, text=u"      Hire      ", command=self.OnButtonClick5)
        button5.grid(column=3, row=4, columnspan=2)

        button6 = tkinter.Button(self, text=u"   Teacher   ", command=self.OnButtonClick6)
        button6.grid(column=3, row=5, columnspan=2)

    def New_Option4(self):
        self.labelVariable6.set(Level)

        self.labelVariable13 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label13 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable13, anchor='e', fg='black')
        label13.grid(column=3, row=2, columnspan=2, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable13.set('Mages:')

        self.labelVariable14 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label14 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable14, anchor='w', fg='black')
        label14.grid(column=5, row=2, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable14.set(Mages)

        self.labelVariable15 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label15 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable15, anchor='e', fg='black')
        label15.grid(column=3, row=3, columnspan=2, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable15.set('Summoners:')

        self.labelVariable16 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label16 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable16, anchor='w', fg='black')
        label16.grid(column=5, row=3, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable16.set(Summoners)

        button7 = tkinter.Button(self, text=u"      Mage      ", command=self.OnButtonClick7)
        button7.grid(column=5, row=4)

        button8 = tkinter.Button(self, text=u"  Summoner  ", command=self.OnButtonClick8)
        button8.grid(column=5, row=5)

    def New_Option5(self):
        self.labelVariable6.set(Level)

        self.labelVariable17 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label17 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable17, anchor='e', fg='black')
        label17.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=3, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable17.set("Monsters to Battle:")

        self.labelVariable18 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label18 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable18, anchor='e', fg='black')
        label18.grid(column=0, row=7, columnspan=3, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable18.set("Mages to Battle:")

        self.labelVariable19 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label19 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable19, anchor='e', fg='black')
        label19.grid(column=0, row=8, columnspan=3, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable19.set("Summoners to Battle:")

        self.entryVariableMonsters = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entryVariableMonsters)
        self.entry.grid(column=3, row=6, columnspan=3, stick='EW')

        self.entryVariableMages = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entryVariableMages)
        self.entry.grid(column=3, row=7, columnspan=3, stick='EW')

        self.entryVariableSummoners = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entryVariableSummoners)
        self.entry.grid(column=3, row=8, columnspan=3, stick='EW')

        self.labelVariable20 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label20 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable20, anchor='e', fg='black')
        label20.grid(column=0, row=9, columnspan=2, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable20.set("Victories:")

        self.labelVariable21 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label21 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable21, anchor='e', fg='black')
        label21.grid(column=0, row=10, columnspan=2, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable21.set("Defeats:")

        self.labelVariable22 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label22 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable22, anchor='w', fg='black')
        label22.grid(column=2, row=9, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable22.set(Victories)

        self.labelVariable23 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label23 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable23, anchor='w', fg='black')
        label23.grid(column=2, row=10, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable23.set(Defeats)

        button10 = tkinter.Button(self, text=u'Relics:', command=self.OnButtonClick10)
        button10.grid(column=3, row=9, rowspan=2, sticky='EW')

        self.labelVariable25 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label25 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable25, anchor='w', fg='black')
        label25.grid(column=4, row=9, rowspan=2, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable25.set(Relics)

        button9 = tkinter.Button(self, text=u"TO BATTLE!", command=self.OnButtonClick9)
        button9.grid(column=5, row=9, rowspan=2, sticky='EW')

        self.labelVariable24 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label24 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable24, anchor='e', fg='black')
        label24.grid(column=0, row=98, columnspan=2, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable24.set("Current Bonus:")

        self.labelVariable26 = tkinter.StringVar()
        label26 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable26, anchor='w', fg='black')
        label26.grid(column=2, row=98, columnspan=2, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable26.set("None")
```

I couldn't add the whole code as it was above the character limit so I just added the different stages

Every "New_OptionX" Command is a new stage, right now I have them setup to enter off certain triggers but I want to activate them all at once using a widget, yet I don't want anyone else using my program being able to do the same. Hence why I want the cheat code in the first place. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is very hard to answer without seeing the code you've written. Why does it take you half an hour to test? What's a "stage"?

Comment: Can you break you code up into functions and then write unit tests for the functions?

Comment: Sorry for not adding the code I was very tired when adding this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    self.labelVariable3 = tkinter.StringVar()
    label3 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable3, anchor='e', fg='black')
    label3.grid(column=0, row=2,columnspan=2,  stick='EW')
    self.labelVariable3.set(u"         Mana:")
```

can be compacted in:

```
    label3 = tkinter.Label(self, text=u"         Mana:", anchor='e', fg='black')
    label3 =.grid(column=0, row=2,columnspan=2,  sticky='EW')
```

Creating a custom class with a Label and an Entry should be useful too.

And nothing prevents you to write, when testing, at the end of your file:

```
New_OptionX()
```